# object with the name of a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

if I create an object of a class, I do:

```
Item *item01 = [[Item alloc] init];
```

but how do I give it a name I have in a string? (I make this question because I have to do this in a loop, and the name of object is dynamic)

```
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", var];
Item *??? = [[Item alloc] init];
```

thanks!

Comment: [`"No, you don't understand," the Knight said, looking a little vexed. "That's what the name
 is called. The name really is 'The Aged, Aged Man.'"`](http://homepages.tcp.co.uk/~nicholson/alice.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object name from String in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888935/object-name-from-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer the object by the name of the string, you would store your objects in [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and set the key to the name.

For example:

```
// Someplace in your controller create and initialize the dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *myItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:40];

// Now when you create your items
Item *temp = [[Item alloc] init];
[myItems setObject:temp forKey:@"item01"];
[temp release];

// This way when you want the object, you just get it from the dictionary
Item *current = [myItems objectForKey:@"item01"];
```

Comment: works ok, but if I wanted to delete item01 from SuperView, how do I? doing so, it does not work '[[myItems objectForKey:@"item01"] removeFromSuperview];'

Comment: So your Item object superclass is UIView?  If so, you should read [UIView continues to exist after removeFromSuperview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514205/uiview-continues-to-exist-after-removefromsuperview)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have variable name from a string. What are you trying to achieve here? You can use dictionary for looking up variable from a string key.

Check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888935/object-name-from-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

the need to change the name of a variable (`Item *???`) is very unusual -- it's often preprocessor abuse.

instead, i think you may be looking to create *instances* of types by name.

to do this use a combination of `id`, `Class` apis, `NSClassFromString`.

`id` is a pointer to an undefined objc object, which the compiler will 'accept' any declared message to:

```
id aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", var];
```

now you can request `aString` to perform selectors it may not respond to. it's similar to a `void*` for an objc type. note that you'll get a runtime exception if you message an `id` variable using a selector it does not respond to.

next, the `Class` type:

```
Class stringClass = [NSString class];
NSString * aString = [stringClass stringWithFormat:@"%@", var];
```

to combine all this to create an instance of a type by name:

```
NSString * className = [stringClass stringWithFormat:@"%@", var];
Class classType = NSClassFromString(className);
assert(classType && "there is no class with this name");
id arg = [[classType alloc] init];
```